# DAX: How to get the Grand total COLUMN (i.e. the total across all columns in a pivot table)

Tags: dax, pivot-table

How do i get a DAX measure to give the the Grand Total COLUMN, for each row?  That highlighted in Yellow in the image.
The measure should work whatever the user selects as different column(s) in their pivot tables

```
        C1  C2  Ctotal
Rowl    1   2   3
Row2    3   4   7
Rtotal  4   6   10
```

There are lots of discussions about totals (and %) using ALL but these are mostly based on rows and no column filtering.  To do this I am looking for an "ALLCOLUMNS" function to remove any column filtering, while keeping the row filtering.

Thanks

I've tried ALL, ALLSELECTED etc but I want to keep the page filters and row filters, and ONLY remove the column filters (to get the column total) WHATEVER the user has selected to show as the columns.  Given the user can select whatever they like as the columns, I don't know how to identify them and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
Row Grand Total :=
CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataTable[Ctotal]),
    ALL(DataTable[C1], DataTable[C2]),
    VALUES(DataTable[Row])
)
```

Comment: Your solution works when the user has put [C] into the columns of the pivot table, but because you have hard-coded [C1] it will NOT work "Whatever the user has selected to show as the columns".  
  
My example is not great, so to improve:  
Imagine the data has VarA, VarB, ..., VarZ, and a measure: Amt.  
A user has put VarA in the rows of a pivot table and VarB in the columns.  
How do I get the total across the columns?  
  
You would use "ALL(VarB}, but if the user changes VarC to the columns this stops working.  
How do i make the DAX work WHATEVER is put on the columns?